# Javascript quiz answer values aren't right

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm making a personal quiz in javascript to see what clothing you want. Most of it works fine, except that the value that I give when I press an answer isn't right.

Html:

```
<div className="container">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <button onClick="NextQuestion()" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
    <button onClick="PrevQuestion()" id="prevbtn" style="display: none;">Previous</button>
    <div id="finalLink"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("finalLink").innerHTML +=
        "<a id='FLink' href='https://www.voetbalshop.nl/voetbalschoenen.html#' onClick='location.href=this.href+getLink(url);return false;'>Result</a>";

    class QuizPart {
        constructor(questionDescription, chosenAnswer, prefix) {
            this.questionDescription = questionDescription;
            this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }
    }

    class ChosenAnswer {
        constructor(id, name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    let Quiz = [
        new QuizPart('Whats your size?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6595', '41'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6598', '42'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6601', '43'),
        ], 'bd_shoe_size_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What color would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6053', 'Red'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6044', 'Blue'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6056', 'Yellow'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6048', 'Green'),
        ], 'color_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What brand would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('5805', 'Adidas'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5866', 'Nike'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5875', 'Puma'),
        ], 'manufacturer_ids='),
    ]
    // console.log(Quiz);

    let url = [];

    let questionNumber = -1;
    let button = document.getElementById('answer');
    let questionName = document.getElementById('question');
    let nextbtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    let prevbtn = document.getElementById('prevbtn')
    let resultbtn = document.getElementById('FLink');

    function NextQuestion() {
        // adds 1 to question to see a different question
        questionNumber++;

        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
            answerButton.style.display = 'none';
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons
            let btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = item.id;
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = item.name;
            button.appendChild(btn);
        }
        // Check if your at the last question so the next button will stop being displayed.
        if (questionNumber > 0) {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'none';
        }

        if (Quiz.length - 1 <= questionNumber) {
            nextbtn.style.display = 'none';
            resultbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        } else {
            nextbtn.style.display = 'block';
            resultbtn.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";
    }

    function PrevQuestion() {
        questionNumber--;
        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
            answerButton.style.display = 'none';
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons

            let btn = document.querySelector('button[value="' + item.id + '"]');
            btn.style.display = 'block';
        }
        //Check if your at the last question so the next button will stop being displayed.
        if (questionNumber < Quiz.length - 1) {
            nextbtn.style.display = 'block';
        }
        if (questionNumber <= 0) {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'block';
        }

        if (Quiz.length - 1 <= questionNumber) {
            resultbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        } else {
            resultbtn.style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the paremeters for the URL.
     *
     * @param {Array} url The parameters .... .
     */
    function getLink(url) {
        let tmp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
            // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
            if (url[i].length > 0) {
                tmp.push("" + Quiz[i].prefix + url[i].join(","))
            }
        }
        /// If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers.
        console.log(url, questionNumber);
        return "" + tmp.join("&");
    };

    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        const tgt = e.target;

        // clear the url array if there's nothing clicked
        if (url.length < questionNumber) {
            url.push([]);
        }

        let quizUrl = url[questionNumber - 1];

        // Check if a button is clicked. Changes color and adds value to the url array.
        if (quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
            quizUrl.push(tgt.value);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
            // Check if a button is clicked again. If clicked again changes color back and deletes value in the url array.
        } else {
            quizUrl.splice(quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value), 1);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        console.log(getLink(url));
    })
```

When I open my site it shows the beginning and when I start the quiz I see my first question with all the answers beneath, but when I click on an answer of the first question I get an error and with the second question, it shows the right value, but in the prefix of the first question etc. It basically always sets the value to the previous question.

Too make it a little clearer all the answers that you give are collected in one variable (url).
At the end it look something like this:

> bd_shoe_size_ids=6732,4765&color_ids=3846,4635&manufacturer_ids=4563,3456

The text in the variable are the questions and the id's the answers that you clicked. When I click on an answer that belongs to manufacturer_ids it sets the answer goes to color_ids abd when click an answer that blongs to color it goed to shoe size.

Can anybody help me with this?

The error that the first question gives is as following:

> (index):188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
> at HTMLDivElement. ((index):188)

Comment: *"I get an error"* . What is the specific error? Details like that are very important to helping troubleshoot

Comment: Is this a React app? Because if so, you should write React code.

Comment: @charlietfl That it doesn't recocnise it because there is no value. The second question answers go to the first question prefix, so when you answer the first question it goes nowhere, because there is no question before the first question. The precise error is this:     >(index):188 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):188)

Comment: [edit] the question to include error details and steps you have taken to try debugging the error

Comment: @ChrisG No i don't use react

Comment: OK so it is telling you that the problem is on line 188 and has to do with indexOf. Which is line 188 in your code? We can't tell the line numbers. Do some troubleshooting in that area

Comment: @charlietfl if (quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
            quizUrl.push(tgt.value);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

Comment: So use your developer tools to find out what is undefined there. Have you checked what the `value` is?

Comment: Well the buttons have have the value of the oop array Quiz. The focus is chosenAnswer and specifically the id's. The first quistion comes from the first Quizpart, the second question from the second quizPart and so on. It's shows everything correctly, but when I answer a question it sets the value to the quizpart previous from the current question. So when I answer the first question it doesn't regocnise it because there is no quizpart before the first one. The problem I'm having is putting the values in the right quizpart

Comment: I thought it might be because you're using `className` and `onClick`, which are typically used in React (especially the first one).

Comment: Did you resolve your problem or do you need help?

Comment: @Pierre No man. Sorry for the late response but i had problems with my laptop so I couldn't answer for a few days

Answer (score 1):

To clear an array, set it to [] or call splice.

Not Correct

```
if (url.length < questionNumber) {
   url.push([]);
}
```

Correct

```
url = []
// or
url.splice(0, url.length)
```

Then there is this

```
let quizUrl = url[questionNumber - 1];
```

If you clear it and not return, that will throw an error.

Put a log statement before this line.

```
console.log(url)
let quizUrl = url[questionNumber - 1];
```

As this line might be the culprit.

```
quizUrl.indexOf(quizUrl)
```

In fact, I do not even see where you add anything to your `url` array besides pushing an empty array.

Comment: That's not the reason it doesn 't work tho. This piece of code works fine for what I need and it doesn't really have anything to do with my question. Another version (without the previous button) has the same code and works fine

Comment: well your question is really vague, and that is what stands out as not making the code work

Comment: The problem is that the value of the givven answers are given to the previous question's prefix.

Comment: your url array might contain the value 'undefined'. i will add to solution

Comment: it adds the targeted value that it pushes so the value of the array answer that is pressed. I fixed the error but when i press the previous button it still does the same. it adds the value to the previous (wrong) prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody found out the obvious problem. You have:

```js
let questionNumber = -1;
//...
function NextQuestion() {
    questionNumber++;
    //...
}
function PreviousQuestion() {
    questionNumber--;
    //...
}
```

So your questionNumber is 0-indexed (first question is 0, second 1, etc.)

The way you fetch the current `quizUrl` is wrong:

```js
let quizUrl = url[questionNumber - 1];
```

For the first question (`questionNumber=0`) you get `url[-1]` which is undefined, thus your error.

You should use:

```js
let quizUrl = url[questionNumber];
```

You can easily debug these kind of errors with a debugger. (see for instance https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/ if you use Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work. Now whenever i press an answer I get this error:                                                                                                                                               Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):179)                                                            
And I still have the same problem when i press the previous button. The values don't add up untill i press next again.